# Rails Ransack: How to get list of attributes which were used for filtering?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ransack

On the search results page I want to display columns which were used for filtering.

Comment: and what's stopping you?

Comment: Need more information.. Currently given information is not helping us to help you..

Comment: I have a ransack object with a query, for ex `Book.ransack(name_eq: 'Super', year_in: [2005, 2006, 2010])`. Now I want to get list of attributes from this ransack object. In my example it will be `['name', 'year']`.